# How to Automate Deficit Value to Next Month Target?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a data table as shown below

| Owner | Month | Year | Target | Achieved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | April | 2021 | 100 | 50 |
| B | April | 2021 | 100 | 80 |
| A | May | 2021 | 100 | 80 |
| B | May | 2021 | 100 | 130 |
| A | June | 2021 | 100 | 50 |
| B | June | 2021 | 100 | 60 |

The logic is if there is a shortfall with respect to Achieved then the shortfall amount should be added to next month target.

For Example A's April Target is 100 and Achieved is 50. The Shortfall would be 100-50=50. The 50 should be added to May Target

The output required as

| Owner | Month | Year | Target | Achieved | Shortfall(Target-Achieved) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | April | 2021 | 100 | 50 | 50 |
| A | May | 2021 | 150 | 80 | 70 |
| A | June | 2021 | 170 | 50 | 120 |
| B | April | 2021 | 100 | 80 | 20 |
| A | May | 2021 | 120 | 130 | -10 |
| B | June | 2021 | 100 | 60 | 40 |

Is it possible to achieve this automation in SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @user12490809 which mysql version do you use? If short fall negative then will it add to next month target?

Comment: Hi I'm using 8.0 version

Answer (score 0):

You want a cumulative sum.  Assuming that the `month` column is really ordered, then the final column is:

```
select t.*,
       sum(target - achieved) over (partition by owner, year
                                    order by month
                                   )
from t;
```

You can use this for the calculation for the new target:

```
select t.*,
       sum(target - achieved) over (partition by owner, year
                                    order by month
                                   )
       (achieved +
        sum(target - achieved) over (partition by owner, year
                                     order by month
                                    )
       ) as new_target
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider year wise all month as ordering purpose if data available. If previous short fall is negative then current row short fall will be calculated as target - achieved otherwise target + prev.shortfall - achieved.

```
-- MySQL(v5.8)
SELECT t.owner, t.month, t.year
     , t.target + (CASE WHEN t.row_num = 1 THEN 0
                        ELSE CASE WHEN LAG(short_fall) OVER (PARTITION BY t.owner ORDER BY t.row_num) < 0
                                     THEN 0
                                  ELSE LAG(short_fall) OVER (PARTITION BY t.owner ORDER BY t.row_num)
                             END 
                   END) target
      , t.achieved
      , CASE WHEN LAG(short_fall) OVER (PARTITION BY t.owner ORDER BY t.row_num) < 0
                THEN t.target - t.achieved
             ELSE short_fall
        END short_fall
FROM (select owner, month
     , year
     , target
     , achieved
     , SUm(target - achieved) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY owner, year ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(month, ' 1, ', year),'%M %d,%Y'), '%c')) short_fall                                                   
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (PARTITION BY owner, year ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(month, ' 1, ', year),'%M %d,%Y'), '%c')) row_num
from test) t;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e114348c2d92015490f76fdbab1c46f

Comment: Hi @user12490809 Please check my answer and let me know if any question.

Comment: hi @user12490809 are you get your expected answer? Everyone try to answer the asked question for helping purpose. Try to give your valuable comment.